# Azure live streaming with already encoded content

Tags: azure, live-streaming, azure-media-services

I have been looking into Azure live streaming features and very impressed with the features they offer.

What I would like to know is, if we can live stream from an already encoded video asset rather than a live recording. 
For an example if I want to stream an event on a specific time with existing VOD content on Azure.

Not sure if there is any support on Wirecast to do this.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested right after I read your question, but currently I failed to publish out existing/already-uploaded Asset as a streaming source in Azure Media Service solely.

In case of WireCast, it can serve media files for streaming as [the manual](https://www.telestream.net/pdfs/user-guides/Wirecast-6-User-Guide-Windows.pdf) describes in page 36.

> Wirecast uses the concept of a shot to construct presentations. A shot contains media,
>   along with the settings for that media. In its simplest form, a shot contains one piece of
>   media such as a photo or a video clip. But it can also be something more complex, like a
>   live camera with a title, and background music, or even a Playlist of shots.

But, if you only want to serve a file without editing, you can use simple encoder program like FFmpeg from your computer (or virtual machine) for transmitting as below documentation suggests.

https://azure.microsoft.com/ko-kr/blog/azure-media-services-rtmp-support-and-live-encoders/

At above link, FFmpeg command line example is as below;

`C:\tools\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -v verbose -i MysampleVideo.mp4 -strict -2 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -r 30 -g 60 -keyint_min 60 -b:v 400000 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -bufsize 400k -maxrate 400k -f flv rtmp://channel001-streamingtest.channel.media.windows.net:1935/live/a9bcd589da4b42409936940/mystream1`

Comment: thanks for the reply. Looks like Wirecast or the FFMPEG are the optons. Sad there is no direct support from Azure for this. Left with one of these two option.

Comment: @user1975173 // I posted at Azure feedback site. Let's vote for applying it sooner :) https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169396-media-services/suggestions/13392156-reuse-asset-for-livestreaming

Comment: Voted for it. Thanks for posting it up there. Lets hope they enable this feature.